# high charts with master-detail and handles

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts to build a chart and I need to use the api that it exposes to do certain things. however I would like my chart to be a master-detail type chart like the one in the highstock library but which has the handles on them.

I know i can create a master-detail in highcharts but it does not seem have the handles for dragging the selected range.

Comment: Hi wergeld, I need to use other parts of the highcharts api that highstock dont seem to have.

Comment: Fair enough. You may also want to try maybe a jQuery slider?

Comment: Sorry @Dave, but what does highchart have that highstock doesn't?

Comment: If you do have a highstock license or if the target deployments meets their licensing terms, you could use highstock's source for the navigator and use it with highcharts too

Comment: Hi Jugal, I've been looking at highstocks as well but it doesn't seem to allow multiple series to be displayed in the master chart, when i looked a few days ago i found a couple of other things that it didn't seem able to do, but i dont have them to hand at the moment.

Comment: @Dave This chart has multiple series, isn't it? http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

Comment: Hi Igor I've seen that example before but the 'master' part only shows one series, I found a work around and will post it as the answer. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used highstock and found an example with multiple series in the 'master' chart which is called 'navigator' the highstock charts.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/davidoleary/NudSK/